# Jacob WMI putOption

Tags: java, com, wmi, jacob

I am using Jacob and have a a requirement to use 'CreateOnly' put option through it. The C# code for this is as follows:

```
PutOptions options = new PutOptions();   
options.Type = PutType.CreateOnly;
```

I need to corresponding Java Jacob code that would work. I have tried a few ways to do this but no success yet.

The link for sample C# code used above is [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560467.aspx).

Jacob is [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/jacob-project/discussion/375946/thread/c6686f18/).

Comment: The link for sample C# code used above is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560467.aspx

Comment: JACOB is https://sourceforge.net/p/jacob-project/discussion/375946/thread/c6686f18/